# Sequelize get username from a comment to a post

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My code returns `user: [Object]` when I console.log my blogpost, just to check if it's working. Here are my models:

```
const User = require('./User');
const Blogpost = require('./Blogpost');
const Comment = require('./Comment');

// ----- User and Blogpost connection
User.hasMany(Blogpost, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});

Blogpost.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id'
});

// ----- User and Comment connection
User.hasMany(Comment, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
});

Comment.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
});

// ----- Blogpost and Comment connection
Blogpost.hasMany(Comment, {
  foreignKey: 'blogpost_id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
});

Comment.belongsTo(Blogpost, {
  foreignKey: 'blogpost_id',
});

module.exports = { User, Blogpost, Comment};
```

Here's the route I have

```
router.get('/blogpost/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const blogpostData = await Blogpost.findByPk(req.params.id, {
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          attributes: ['username']
        },
        {
          model: Comment,
          include: [
            {
              model: User,
              attributes: ['username'],
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
  });

  const blogposts = blogpostData.get({ plain: true});

  console.log(blogposts)

  res.render('blogpost', {
      ...blogposts,
      logged_in: req.session.logged_in
  });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
})
```

See that console.log(blogposts) is where I'm getting [object]. Specifically, this is what I'm getting:

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Post title',
  content: 'Post content',
  date_created: 2020-05-08T06:00:00.000Z,
  user_id: 1,
  user: { username: 'X' },
  comments: [
    {
      id: 1,
      comment_text: 'Nice!',
      user_id: 2,
      blogpost_id: 1,
      user: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've asked chatGPT and tried several things

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not working on backend, but on frontend when I do `{{user.username}}` (using handlebars) it does show up the username. Weird!